How to filter a Firebase query whether or not the query parameter exists
How can I adjust the Firebase query expression below to accommodate missing query parameters?
admin.firestore().collection('vehicles').where('type', '==', request.query['car'])

The expression above works when ?car=ford is passed as part of the GET request. I would like to use something like the following whenever the query parameter is not passed:
admin.firestore().collection('vehicles').where('type', '==', [request.query['car'] || ***the current vehicle type***])

Do you have any suggestions?

If I correctly understand, the "current vehicle type" is somehow known in your front end (e.g. you have it in a variable or in a field) or in your server side or Cloud Function code (you use the Admin SDK).
If this is the case, you just have to calculate the desired value for the third argument of the where() method before using it. Something along the following lines:
function isNullOrUndefined(value) {
   return value === undefined || value === null;
}

const currentVehicleType = ...; 
const filterValue = isNullOrUndefined(request.query['car']) ? currentVehicleType : request.query['car'];
const q = admin.firestore().collection('vehicles').where('type', '==', filterValue);


The API request could be https://vehicles.wxyz.app?type=ford or https://vehicles.wxyz.app. In the former case, I want a filtered list. In the latter case, I want the entire list. In the comparison, where('type', '==', filterValue) type is compared to currentVehicleType when there is not a query value. currentVehicleType in that case cannot be known. In SQL, I would compare a field value to itself whenever a parameter is not passed in. I would like to do something like that here.

Ok, since
admin.firestore().collection('vehicles').where('type', '==', [request.query['car'] || ***the current vehicle type***])

will not work when a query parameter is not part of the API call, the solution is to filter after the collection is obtained. The following works:
admin.firestore().collection('vehicles').get()
   .then(results => {
      let tempDoc = results.docs.map((doc) => {
         return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}
      });
      if(!!request.query['type']){
         tempDoc = tempDoc.filter((x:any) => x['type'] === request.query['type']);
      }
});

The bottom line: the .where clause is insufficient to handle filtering for when a query parameter is passed and for when a query parameter is not passed.
